# What is Drupal's default password encryption method?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am trying to figure out what is the security that Drupal 6/7 uses by default to store passwords. Is it MD5, AES, SHA? I have been unable to find anything.

Comment: "_I have been unable to find anything._" - Ok, normally, I don't do 'have you tried google' comments, but this is ridiculous - did you even _try_ to find something? (Hint: copy and paste your questions title into a google search box)

Comment: I did.  And it brought me to Stack Overflow.  :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Drupal 8 and Drupal 7 use SHA512 by default with a salt. They run the hash through PHP's [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function numerous times to increase the computation cost of generating a password's final hash (a security technique called [stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)).

With Drupal 8, the implementation is object oriented. There is a [PasswordInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PasswordInterface.php/interface/PasswordInterface/8) which defines a hash method. The default implementation of that interface is in the [PhpassHashedPassword](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/class/PhpassHashedPassword/8) class. That class' [hash](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword::hash/8) method calls the [crypt](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Password!PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword::crypt/8) method passing in SHA512 as the hashing algorithm, a password, and a generated salt. The class' crypt method is nearly the same as Drupal 7's [_password_crypt()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7) method.

With Drupal 7, the implementation is split into a couple global functions: [user_hash_password()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) and [_password_crypt()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--password.inc/function/_password_crypt/7).

Drupal 6 uses MD5 without a salt. The relevant function is [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/6).

Comment: It is worth noting that Drupal 7/8 uses a modified version of [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) which can be found under the the [Secure Password Hashes](https://drupal.org/project/phpass) module.

Answer (score 42):

Here is an example hash from Drupal 7:

- "pass" : "$S$Dxl65W9p07LfQU7jvy5CnsyDpMoLujiAgzy123khcg1OJi/P9pKS"
- The characters 0-2 are the type ( $S$ is Drupal 7 )
- The character  3 is the number of log2 rounds (X) based on the position of the char in this list:
  './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' So in our example 'D' would map to 15
- The characters 4-11 are the SALT
- The rest is a SHA512 hash using 2^X rounds.
- The binary result is then converted to a string using base64.

  $count = 1 << $count_log2;
  $hash = hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE);
  do { $hash = hash($algo, $hash . $password, TRUE);
  } while (--$count);

The whole process can be found in:
mydrupalsite\includes\password.inc

Answer (score 12):

It can be checked inside www\includes\password.inc

```
function user_check_password($password, $account) {
  if (substr($account->pass, 0, 2) == 'U$') {
    // This may be an updated password from user_update_7000(). Such hashes
    // have 'U' added as the first character and need an extra md5().
    $stored_hash = substr($account->pass, 1);
    $password = md5($password);
  }
  else {
    $stored_hash = $account->pass;
  }

  $type = substr($stored_hash, 0, 3);
  switch ($type) {
    case '$S$':
      // A normal Drupal 7 password using sha512.
      $hash = _password_crypt('sha512', $password, $stored_hash);
      break;
    case '$H$':
      // phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing as "$P$".
    case '$P$':
      // A phpass password generated using md5.  This is an
      // imported password or from an earlier Drupal version.
      $hash = _password_crypt('md5', $password, $stored_hash);
      break;
    default:
      return FALSE;
  }
  return ($hash && $stored_hash == $hash);
}
```

Its been clearly written that "// A normal Drupal 7 password using sha512."

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 6 core, the method uses MD5 and as I understand it, there isn't any salting used. For drupal 7 some more advanced hashing is used. A good article on it here - http://joncave.co.uk/2011/01/password-storage-in-drupal-and-wordpress/

Comment: Drupal 6 is no longer supported by the community, but there is a contributed module to make Drupal 6 core us the much stronger PHPASS mechanism: https://www.drupal.org/project/phpass

Answer (score 0):

drupal 8 is using Phpass (modified version)

drupal 7 use SHA-512 + salt

drupal 6 and previous version were using md5 with no salt

Answer (score 0):

Here is the links I found from drupal.org:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Password%21PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword%3A%3Acrypt/8.2.x
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Password%21PhpassHashedPassword.php/function/PhpassHashedPassword%3A%3Ahash/8.2.x