# Magento : Converting drupal password to magento passwords

Tags: magento, drupal-7, password-encryption

I am working on migration project from drupal to magento. Anyone knows how to convert the Drupal password to Magento 1.9 format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your question you have written you are migrating from Magento to drupal , then why do you want to convert drupal password to Magento?

Comment: Please check the question. Let me know the exact question.

Comment: Sorry Guys, I have updated the question :) Thanks Muk for pointing me out!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this answer [What is Drupal's default password encryption method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031662/what-is-drupals-default-password-encryption-method) it appears (as suspected) you wouldn't be able to reverse it (depending on version).

Magento uses an MD5 hash (with salt) when supplied.

My suggestion would be to re-engineer Magento's login option to use the same encryption method as Drupal.  You could test this by copying `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php` in the first instance and implementing your changes there. Then look for an observer method you could utilise moving forward or rewrite the item.